# How can I avoid the duplicate code of mapping in Spring project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am currently **mapping** pages using `Page Controller`.

Every page needs to check for `Session`, which is a **duplicate code**.

How do I avoid duplicating this code?

```java
@Controller
public class PageController {
...
    @RequestMapping("/view/List")
    public String list(Map<String, Object> model) {
        String session_chk = Utils.SessionCheck(); 
        if(session_chk.equals("none")){
            return "/view/manager/Login";
        }

        return "/view/member/List";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/view/Detail")
    public String detail(Map<String, Object> model) {
        String session_chk = Utils.SessionCheck();
        if(session_chk.equals("none")){
            return "/view/manager/Login";
        }

        return "/view/member/Detail";
    }
...
```

Comment: you can add a servlet filter

Comment: Hi @user7294900  I know about servlets, but I don't know how to add them.

Comment: Why do you don't use Spring Security support ? It could help you to avoid that duplicate code

Comment: @EduardoEljaiek I don't know much about spring yet. How can you avoid duplication by using it?

Comment: Is "/view/manager/Login" your only login URL ?

Comment: @EduardoEljaiek Yes

Comment: Ok I'll cook you an example and also will provide you with useful documentation links in my answer

Comment: see my updated filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a filter which will redirect, and add check

```
@Component
public class SessionFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (!request.getRequestURI().contains("view/manager/Login") && "none".equals(Utils.SessionCheck())) {
      httpResponse.sendRedirect("view/manager/Login.jsp");
      //....
    } else {
      doFilterInternal(request, response, filterChain);
    }
}
```

You can add it to all urls:

```
FilterRegistration sessionFilter = servletContext.addFilter("SessionFilter", SessionFilter.class);
sessionFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
```

Comment: I want to avoid duplicating the same code. Does that mean you have to add the above code to each mapping page?

Comment: @hongdevelop no, just once

Comment: Where should I add it to the Page Controller JavaFile?

Comment: The filter needs to check if path is for `/view/manager/Login` and not do a redirect in this case otherwise you get stuck in the loop. You can use the methods on `HttpServletResponse` to check.

Comment: @AlanHay Thanks, added `!request.getRequestURI().contains( "view/manager/Login" )`

Answer (score 6):

You could use Spring Security to avoid all duplicate code related with securing your web application and also it provides buit-in protection against attacks such as *session fixation*, *clickjacking* or *cross site request forgery*. It is the de-facto standard for securing Spring-based applications.

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/security-spring) you can find a nice series of tutorials to learn *Spring Security*.

[Here](https://github.com/eljaiek/spring-security-demo) you can find an small example in where you'll see how I handled a similar situation to yours using *Spring Security* configuration only.

[image: Example Running]

This is my *Spring Security* configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {    
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user1").password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1Pass")).roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("user2").password(passwordEncoder().encode("user2Pass")).roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("adminPass")).roles("ADMIN");      
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {     
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                // Only users with admin role will access views starting with /admin
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
               //  Anonymous users (users without sessions) will access this URL
                .antMatchers("/anonymous*").anonymous()
               // Allowing all users to access login page
                .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.html")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage.html", true)              
                .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/perform_logout")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler())
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");     
    }

    @Bean
    public LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler() {
        return new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```